# ARRAY_BUFFER lost after VAO binded to null in WebGL

Tags: firefox, binding, webgl, vbo, vao

I created a VAO and bound the VBOs for the VAO to remember those bindings:

```
bufferV = gl.createBuffer ();
bufferI = gl.createBuffer ();
vertexArray = gl.createVertexArray ();
gl.bindVertexArray (vertexArray);
gl.bindBuffer (gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferI);
gl.bindBuffer (gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferV);
gl.bindVertexArray (null);
```

In the animation loop, I rebind the VAO to rebind the VBOs and load some vertices and indices into them before rendering (I already created the shaders, the program, and activated the program):

```
gl.bindVertexArray (vertexArray);
gl.bufferData (gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array (vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
gl.bufferData (gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array (indices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
// Call to gl.drawElements () here
gl.bindVertexArray (null);
```

And then, because I want to do this (don't ask me why), at the end of the animation loop, I unbind the VBOs:

```
gl.bindBuffer (gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, null);
gl.bindBuffer (gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, null);
```

A strange thing occurs. After the first loop, WebGL reports:

```
WebGL warning: bufferData: Buffer for `target` is null.
```

I checked. It means that after the first loop, binding the VAO does *NOT* restore the ARRAY_BUFFER VBO binding. But it still restores the ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER VBO binding. May somebody explain why? I tested on Firefox 90.0.2 for Windows.

**EXAMPLE TO HELP PEOPLE DISCOVERING HOW THE VAO STATE WORKS REGARDING THE BINDINGS TO ARRAY_BUFFER AND ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER**

Thanks to the answers to my question, I'm please to give this little standalone example which shows how this VAO state stuff works.

```
var program, vs, fs, bufferXY, bufferRGB, bufferI, vao, location, buffer;
var vertices = [    // x, y
    0.0, 1.0,
    1.0, -1.0,
    -1.0, -1.0
];
var colors = [  // r, g, b
     1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
      0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
       0.0, 0.0, 1.0
];
var indices = [
    0, 1, 2
];
var nbIndicesPerPrimitive=3, nbPrimitives=1;

// We create two shaders and a program.

vs = gl.createShader (gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
gl.shaderSource (vs, "#version 300 es\nin lowp vec2 A_xy;in lowp vec3 A_rgb;out lowp vec4 V_rgba;void main (void) { gl_Position = vec4 (A_xy, 0.0, 1.0); V_rgba = vec4 (A_rgb, 1.0); }");
gl.compileShader (vs);
if (!gl.getShaderParameter (vs, gl.COMPILE_STATUS))
    console.log (gl.getShaderInfoLog (vs));
fs = gl.createShader (gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
gl.shaderSource (fs, "#version 300 es\nin lowp vec4 V_rgba;out lowp vec4 rgba;void main (void) { rgba = V_rgba; }");
gl.compileShader (fs);
if (!gl.getShaderParameter (fs, gl.COMPILE_STATUS))
    console.log (gl.getShaderInfoLog (fs));
program = gl.createProgram ();
gl.attachShader (program, vs);
gl.attachShader (program, fs);
gl.linkProgram (program);
gl.useProgram (program);

// We create some VBOs and a VAO.

bufferXY = gl.createBuffer ();
bufferRGB = gl.createBuffer ();
bufferI = gl.createBuffer ();
vao = gl.createVertexArray ();

// We bind bufferXY to ARRAY_BUFFER. We can do it before the VAO is bound, because the ARRAY_BUFFER binding is global state. This means that whatever VBO is bound to ARRAY_BUFFER when vertexAttribPointer () is called, it will be memorized in the VAO state for the attribute which location is passed to this function.

gl.bindBuffer (gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferXY);
gl.bufferData (gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array (vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

// We bind the VAO so that it starts memorizing calls to a set of functions. For WebGL 1, those are bindBuffer () when binding a VBO to ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexAttribPointer (), enableVertexAttribute () and disableVertexAttribute (). WebGL 2 adds some functions to this set: vertexAttribIPointer (), vertexAttribI4[u]i[v] () and vertexAttribDivisor ().

gl.bindVertexArray (vao);

// We bind bufferI to ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER. The VAO memorizes this binding.

gl.bindBuffer (gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferI);
gl.bufferData (gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array (indices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

// We configure attribute A_xy. The VAO memorizes this configuration, including the fact that bufferXY is bound to ARRAY_BUFFER when vertexAttribPointer () is called. So the VAO memorizes that A_xy should be read from bufferXY, 2 floats at a time, starting from offset 0, jumping 2 floats after one read.

location = gl.getAttribLocation (program, "A_xy");
gl.vertexAttribPointer (location, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 2 * Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT, 0);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray (location);

// We configure attribute A_rgb. For this, we must bind bufferRGB to ARRAY_BUFFER. The VAO memorizes this configuration, including the fact that bufferRGB is bound to ARRAY_BUFFER when vertexAttribPointer () is called. So the VBO memorizes that A_rgb should be read from bufferRGB, 3 floats at a time, starting from offset 0, jumping 3 floats after one read. Notice that binding bufferRGB to ARRAY_BUFFER does not change anything to what the VAO memorized about A_xyz previously.

gl.bindBuffer (gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferRGB);
gl.bufferData (gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array (colors), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
location = gl.getAttribLocation (program, "A_rgb");
gl.vertexAttribPointer (location, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 3 * Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT, 0);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray (location);

// We unbind the VAO so that it stops memorizing.

gl.bindVertexArray (null);

// We bind null to ARRAY_BUFFER and to ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER. This will show that all the bindings to ARRAY_BUFFER and ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER will be remembered when the VAO is bound again before rendering.

gl.bindBuffer (gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, null);
gl.bindBuffer (gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, null);

// We start the rendering process.

gl.clearColor (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
gl.clear (gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

// We bind the VAO so that it restores its state, among which the bindings of bufferI to ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, and the bindings of bufferXY to ARRAY_BUFFER for attribute A_xy and of bufferRGB to ARRAY_BUFFER for attribute A_rgb.

gl.bindVertexArray (vao);
gl.drawElements (gl.TRIANGLES, nbIndicesPerPrimitive * nbPrimitives, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
gl.bindVertexArray (null);

// We clean everything.

gl.useProgram (null);
gl.deleteProgram (program);
gl.deleteShader (vs);
gl.deleteShader (fs);
gl.deleteVertexArray (vao);
gl.deleteBuffer (bufferXY);
gl.deleteBuffer (bufferRGB);
gl.deleteBuffer (bufferI);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ARRAY_BUFFER` is a global state. However, the `ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` buffer binding is stored in the Vertex Array Object. Therefor you need to bind the Vertex Array Object when you want to change the `ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` binding:

```js
gl.bindVertexArray (vertexArray);
gl.bindBuffer (gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, null);
```

Each attribute which is stated in the VAOs state vector may refer to a different `ARRAY_BUFFER`. This reference is stored when `gl.vertexAttribPointer` is called. Then the buffer which is currently bound to the `ARRAY_BUFFER` target, is associated to the specified attribute index and the the buffer object reference is stored in the state vector of the currently bound VAO.
However the index buffer is a state of the VAO. A VAO can only refer to 1 index buffer. If a buffer is bound to the `ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` target, the buffer reference is assigned to the currently bound Vertex Array Object.

Comment: Enlightening. I did not notice how that the VAO was operating in such different ways regarding the kind of VBO. Thanks.

Comment: As a follow-up: may you clarify what does "VERTEX ATTRIB ARRAY BUFFER BINDING" refer to, as I read page 242 of the OpenGL ES 3.0.5 specification describing the contents of the VAO state (table 6.2)? What OpenGL function call does it "log"?

Comment: @StashOfCode This is part of the state vector and refers to the "VBO". The state vector has 1 item per attribute.